# How to limit the amount of characters allowed in a databound WinForms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have text boxes that are data bound to a field in a database and am using Entity Framework. The limit on the field is 10. How can I have the control recognize this limit?

Comment: WPF, ASP.NET, WinForms, what?

Answer (score 2):

Mark up your entitiy metadata with the following Data Annotation:

```
[StringLength(4, ErrorMessage = "The string value cannot exceed 4 characters. ")]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959

Comment: Where would I add that in a winform?

Comment: I added a link to a helpful article. As far as winforms is concerned... well i havent run into that specific combo. I know you can use this validation technique with WPF and Silverlight but im not sure about winforms.

Comment: Article is hardly helpful because it talks about ASP.NET MVC 3 which have native support for data annotations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection between data annotation / entity framework metadata and winform controls = it will not set `MaxLength` for you or add automatic validation.